# AEM ResourceResolverFactory null in HTL component java class

Tags: aem, sling

I have a HTL component class like

```
MyComponent extends WCMUser{
@Reference
private ResourceResolverFactory  resourceResolverFactory;
```

But when i am trying to use it i am getting NullPointerException on same.

I even tried using @Service & @Component SCR tags but no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, so i can create another service, get ResourceResolverFactory  there. Once there i can use ResourceResolverFactory in this service or pass it to WCMUse class.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `@Reference` or other annotations with your Java Use API since it is not treated as an OSGi service. Instead use the `getSlingScriptHelper()` to get the `SlingScriptHelper` object which can then be used to get the services.

```
public MyComponent extends WCMUsePojo {

    public void activate() {
        getSlingScriptHelper().getService(<<SomeService.class>>);
    }
}
```

However if it is only the `ResourceResolver` that you need you can call the `getResourceResolver()` method available within `WCMUsePojo` class.

More information on Java Use-API can be found [in this official doc](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/use-api/java.html#Context).